# XSD: xs:import fails while loading XSD with different case

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am working on generating Jaxb object from a complex XSD . There are XSD which get imported in other xsds which is causing problem. this is how it differs

My actual XSD file name is: `xsdname.v6.xsd`

```
<xs:import namespace="urn::xsdname:v6" schemaLocation="XsdName.v6.xsd"/> 
<xs:import  namespace="urn::xsdname:v6" schemaLocation="xsdname.v6.xsd"/>
```

The error I get is

```
line 10039 of /src/main/schema/external/xsdname.v6.xsd
  'RefundDateTime' is already defined  
line 10048 of src/main/schema/external/XsdName.v6.xsd
  (related to above error) the first definition appears here
```

I was under the assumption that catalog files will help resolve the issue, but it is not using different URLs. It is looking locally, but it's loading it twice.

Any suggestion how this can be resolved?

Comment: Linux file systems are case-sensitive, so that's why. Only have one import, and make sure it matches the casing of the actual file name. Rename the file if needed.

Comment: @Andreas the imports are in different files. 1 xsd has 1 import only but across other xsds it uses different cases, it completely random which xsd uses which import. The xsds are not maintained by our team so i dont have control on them.

Comment: Maybe the case difference is ignored and so you're in the situation to have two imports with the same name... (So try a different name for one of the files)

Answer (score 0):

The schemaLocation is a URI (not a Linux filename...). The processor is likely to recognize that when you have two imports for the same URI, one of them is redundant. But there is no perfect way of comparing whether two URIs are "the same", unless they consist of exactly the same character sequence. Some processors may attempt some normalization (e.g. if they are file system URIs, the processor may check to see if the file system is case-blind), others won't even try. In general, if you import the same schema document more than once by different names, you can expect conflicts.

Comment: as of now i resolved this by replacing the different case elements while dependency resolution. I am not sure if there an actual way to solve this.